# Let $X$ be a non-zero real NLS , $x,y \in X$ , $B(x,r)\subseteq B(y,s)$ , then is it true that $r \le s$ ?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a non-zero real NLS , $x,y \in X$ , $B(x,r)\subseteq B(y,s)$ , then is it true that $r \le s$ ? If $y=x$ then it is easy to see that that's the case . So I thought let $y \ne x$ ; I tried doing the contrapositive that let $r>s$ and tries showing $B(x,r)$ contains a point not in $B(y,s)$ ; I tried taking something like $x+\dfrac{(r+s)(y-x)}{2||y-x||}$ but to no avail . Please help . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $r>s$. Then you can find points $A,B$ in $B(x,r)$ of distance $2r>2s$. Then $d(A,B)\leq d(A,y)+d(y,B)\leq 2s$, a contradiction.